# How to handle session timeout popup middle of test execution of web application using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

While doing automation testing, if the execution takes time then web application session time is expiring. The session timeout popup is geting scanned, which is an error scenario. Please tell me how to handle this type of scenario.

Iam using selenium+java

Comment: Are you getting the session timeout popup message even you are interacting with web app through selenium?

Comment: show your code trials

Comment: try to refresh page .driver.navigate.refresh().